# How to make NTP work despite a high offset?

Tags: redhat, ntp, rhel6, ntpd

Recently I have kickstarted some servers that had their time off by a month in the bios. The time in the bios said it was a random time/date in May, while it was June.

This caused NTP not to work, because NTP doesn't sync with such a high offset. How can I make sure that NTP syncs despite the offset, in this case a month, being too high?

Answer (score 5):

See `-g` option for `ntpd`; set in `/etc/sysconfig/ntpd`. (IMO, running both ntpd and ntpdate is distasteful.)

Comment: On CentOS 6, I believe /etc/sysconfig/ntpd defaults to: 
OPTIONS="-u ntp:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g"

Comment: For this to work for me I had to use the following steps 'sudo service ntp stop' 'ntpq -gq' and 'sudo service ntp start'

Answer (score 1):

For EL5 and EL6:

Start `ntpdate` as well.

It should be sufficient to enable them in your kickstart.

```
%post
chkconfig ntpdate on
chkconfig ntpd on
```

Answer (score 1):

Running the following from the command line should force an update despite any time difference.

```
ntpd -gq
```